# Convergence / divergence examination $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{k}{\left(a \right)}}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{k}{\left(a \right)}}{k}$
Examination of a series depending on a real parameter a.

Can I use the squeeze theorem for series with the $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$ series to judge this series and conclude that it is divergent? The exception would then be for a = 0, when the series is convergent. Or is the example solved completely differently and does it need some additional knowledge?

(I consider the absolute value of the sine, which is at most equal to 1)

(For the $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$series, I assume divergence )

Comment: No. You can't use the squeeze theorem in that way. It works only for convergent series. In factor, given $-1<0<1$ you have $\sum -1 < \sum 0 < \sum 1$ where the middle series is convergent and the rest are divergent.

Comment: I guess I translated it incorrectly, we have it defined differently, it was actually meant, as it is from a colleague in the post below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If $\sin(a)=0$, then the series obviously converges.
- If $\sin(a)=1$, then the series rewrites $\displaystyle{\sum \frac{1}{k}}$ which diverges.
- If $\sin(a)=-1$, then the series rewrites $\displaystyle{\sum \frac{(-1)^k}{k}}$ which converges by Alternating Test.
- If $|\sin(a)| < 1$ and $\sin(a) \neq 0$, then one has
  $$\left|\frac{\sin^{k+1}(a)/(k+1)}{\sin^k(a)/k}\right| = \left|\sin(a)\right| \times \frac{k+1}{k} \longrightarrow \left|\sin(a) \right|$$

Because $|\sin(a)| < 1$, then by the ratio test, the series converges.

In conclusion, the series converges iff $\sin(a) \neq 1$, i.e.
$$\boxed{\text{the series converges iff } a  \neq \dfrac{\pi}{2} \text{ mod } 2\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you, it's actually simple, you just have to think about the individual cases

Comment: pi / 2 mod pi is the same as pi / 2 + 2kpi, k is an integer?

Comment: @martin1288822 There was a typo, it is $\text{mod } 2\pi$, which is indeed the same thing as "$... + 2 k \pi$, $k$ integer".

Answer (score 0):

1)For $0 \le |\sin a | <1$ :

Let $k\ge 2$, $r:=|\sin a|;$

$|\dfrac{\sin^k a} {k}| < r^k$;

Comparison test: $\sum r^k$, the geometric series, converges for $0 \le r <1$;

The original series is absolutely convergent, hence convergent.

2)For $\sin a =-1$ the alternating series $\sum \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k}$ converges.

3)For $\sin a =1$ the series $\sum \dfrac{1}{k}$ diverges.

For which values of $a$ is this the case?